# "Changed by" column for node list

Tags: views, nodes, 8

If a node is changed by another user, the change time is shown on /admin/content but not by which user the node was changed. I couldn't find any field in the respective view to add. Did I miss sth?

Answer (score 0):

- Edit the "Content" view.
- Add "User - Content revision" in Relationships under "Advanced" tab.
- Add "Name - User" in the fields using the Revision user relationship. You can set a label for this field as "Last modified by".

Comment: I tried it, but it still shows the content creator...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on normal "Content" view. Try creating a "content revisions" view type. It lists all the revisions along with user who created the revision, but need to find a way to group by node id. A views query alter may help.

I believe you have already enabled "Create new revision" in content type publishing options.